# How to choose digital potentiometer bandwidth for filter?

Tags: active-filter, band-pass

We want to use a Digital potentiometer for an active bandpass filter. But we do not know how to choose the bandwidth of the potentiometer. The center frequency of the filter will be 90MHz. Should I use a potentiometer above this frequency?
E.g; AD5116 64-Position Digital Potentiometers bandwidth is 4MHz. If we use this potentiometer in the filter we will make, what will we encounter?

In addition, what bandwidth would a potentiometer be sufficient for this filter?

Comment: Which of the filter parameters do you intend to vary?

Comment: what LvW says. No matter what, digital potentiometers that you could use for this do not exist in my experience, but even suggesting alternatives is impossible without knowing *what* about the filter you want to make adjustable. I'd suggest accepting Andy's answer, followed by asking a new question, describing the *job* that your active filter has in your overall system, explaining what you need to vary, and within which ranges, and under what performance metrics and constraints! Ask for a solution to your actual problem – digital potentiometers aren't it.

Comment: (it's very possible that "adjustable active bandpass filter" is not what you're going to end up with, because these are very hard to implement well for RF signals, but there's a whole world of alternatives that might make sense, depending on what this is for. I will not be taking questions to these alternatives in the comments to this question, because that would be very confusing for future readers; so please do ask a new question!)

Comment: Start again, looking at L-C filters, possibly tunable with a varicap diode.

Answer (score 3):

> *The center frequency of the filter will be 90MHz.*

That pretty much **rules out** digi-pots because of their inherent parasitic capacitance on all pins. For instance, the A and B terminals of the [AD5116](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD5116.pdf) has typically 20 pF and, the wiper has typically 35 pF.

At 90 MHz, a capacitance of 20 pF has an impedance (reactance) of 88 ohms and is very significant as a show-stopper for a filter design.

> *If we use this potentiometer in the filter we will make, what will we
> encounter?*

It's not going to work by any stretch of the imagination.

Comment: can confirm. As a student, worked in the same lab as someone trying to make a ca 4 MHz adjustable LPF with a digipot. Bandwidths as stated in the data sheet (ADI, not some noname cheapo vendor) were pretty optimistic given a slightly non-ideal voltage source as input.